# Can't declare a global variable inside IF statement (Pine Script)

Tags: if-statement, global-variables, pine-script

I am new to Pine Script and have some problem declaring a variable inside an if and use it inside another if...

In the **first if statement**, I tried to get the "close price" of the long signal (**LongPrice**).
And in the **second if**, I tried to get the "close price" of the short signal (**ShortPrice**) and subtract it from "LongPrice".
But the value of "LongPrice" not changed outside its own if statement!

From what I understand this means that the variable is not valid outside of the if statement. Is there a way to change this?

```
LongPrice = 0
ShortPrice = 0

if mmeLong
    LongPrice = close  // Get the Long signal's close price
    label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(LongPrice), 
         color=color.green, 
         textcolor=color.white,
         style=label.style_labelup, yloc=yloc.belowbar)

if mmeShort
    ShortPrice = close - LongPrice  // Get the Short signal's close price and minus it with the last Long close price.
    label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(ShortPrice), 
         color=color.red, 
         textcolor=color.white,
         style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make it global with `:=` when you what to declare it again.

```
var float LongPrice = na
var float ShortPrice = na

if mmeLong
    LongPrice := close  // Get the Long signal's close price
    label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(LongPrice), 
         color=color.green, 
         textcolor=color.white,
         style=label.style_labelup, yloc=yloc.belowbar)

if mmeShort
    ShortPrice := close - LongPrice  // Get the Short signal's close price and minus it with the last Long close price.
    label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(ShortPrice), 
         color=color.red, 
         textcolor=color.white,
         style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```